# LibGDX - how do I make my text centered?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm new to LibGDX and I am taking it slowly. I'm still trying to understand most things which is why typically google searches don't help due to the fact that their too complicated. I have a main menu that has text that I want centered no matter what the screen size is. Here is the code that I have for that menu.

```
public class Menu implements Screen {

SlingshotSteve game;

OrthographicCamera camera;

public Menu(final SlingshotSteve gam) {
    this.game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Slingshot Steve!!! ", 100, 150);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap anywhere to begin!", 100, 100);
    game.batch.end();

    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen((Screen) new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm here to save you!

To get width / height from a String drawn with your BitmapFont you can utilize this super nice method:

```
game.font.getBounds(String string)
```

And to use it in your case, it would be something like this:

```
game.font.getBounds("Tap anywhere to begin!").width / 2;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it the way *Nine Magics* suggested, however one would usually do it via a `Stage`, which is part of [`scene2d`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

More specifically one would use [scene2d.ui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui) which is a bunch of `Actor`s like `Button`, `Image`, `Label` etc. You can attach a `ClickListener` to a `Button` for example and react on this event.

Furthermore, for layouting there is one very powerful `Actor`, namely [`Table`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table) which you can very easily use to center things on the screen.

Some very minimalistic code:

```
// do this once, in create() or show()
Skin skin = new Skin("uiskin.json"); // get the demo skin from the libgdx test resources
Stage stage = new Stage();
Table table = new Table(skin);
table.add("Welcome to Slingshot Steve!!!");
table.row();
table.add("Tap anywhere to begin!");
stage.addActor(table);

// do this in your render loop
stage.act();
stage.draw();
```

You can find the "default" skin resources [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data). You need to get all the uiskin.* files.